# Weaker version of corollary (but still formal)

Tags: single-word-requests

I have found much utility in the word "corollary," but there are times when I think it would be better to use a watered-down version. Here is a basic example for illustration purposes:

> The _______ of drive-by-wire is greater attention to digital
> integration with the car.

One could make the case for using corollary here, but it may not be a perfect fit (after all, drive-by-wire could just be for utilitarian, ease-of-use purposes, not making everything software-heavy).

Essentially, I would prefer to have a word like corollary, but also implies plurality (other explanations exist). I'm fine with an academic/formal writing tone; would prefer not to change to casual.

Comment: In American English, I don't think we use *corollary* in the way you describe. Maybe try *byproduct*?

Comment: What meaning do you intend the quote to convey?

Comment: Do you mean *consequence?*